# Is it possible to export HTML to PDF or generate PDF in AngularJs without using JSPDF, Phantom, etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf-generation, angular-directive

I need to export any HTML (e.g. from a `div`) to PDF using AngularJS only. I've googled a lot but I'm unable to find any solution to generate PDFs in AngularJS without the use of libraries such as JSPDF, phantom, etc.

Is there any directive or event available for PDF generation in AngularJS?
I am not looking for a PDF viewer. I am looking for PDF generation.

Comment: in the browser? and library recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://medium.com/@darilldrems/angularjs-export-html-table-to-pdf-excel-or-doc-formats-bb741d06dfec

Comment: Still kind of a library but maybe of interest for you: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post and maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for but maybe it will help you (or others) anyway:

```
var divContent = document.getElementById('yourDiv').innerHTML,
    printWindow = window.open("", "", "width=800, height=600");

printWindow.document.write(divContent);
printWindow.print();
```

This should open a print dialog that allows you to save the HTML as PDF. Note that on some browsers the above method only works when popups are enabled for the site.